# How to set the default time zone in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to get current time of system using mysql query.

I try out NOW() function and it's return

```
2017-11-07 05:36:16
```

but my system time is

```
2017-11-07 11:06:16.
```

How to get to exact system time?

How to implement in mysql query?

Comment: check your server timing.

Comment: Use `date_default_timezone_set('YOUR_TIMEZONE')` for getting date and time as per your system time. Like if you are in India, `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata')`.

Comment: @YashParekh if you have answer post it on answer, it helps other too.

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Thanks for that man, did the same you told.

Comment: Yes good job @YashParekh

Comment: The default time zone is probably UTC or GMT, but do you have a reason for wanting to change that?

Answer (score 1):

There are a [number of ways](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) to do this according to the MySQL documentation.

Following the documentation, open your `my.cnf` file (MySQL configuration). On Linux, that is usually under `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. On Windows, see [other places to look](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Add this line and restart MySQL.

```
default-time-zone='[TIMEZONE]'
```

Replace `[TIMEZONE]` with the timezone you prefer to use.

> The value can be given as a string indicating an offset from UTC, such
>   as '+10:00' or '-6:00'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_default_timezone_set('YOUR_TIMEZONE')` for getting date and time as per your system time.

Like if you are in India, `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata')`

You can find all [Supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) here.

Happy Coding :-)